# How can I compute a rolling sum using groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-sum

I'm working on a fun side project and would like to compute a moving sum for number of wins for NBA teams over 2 year periods. Consider the sample pandas dataframe below,

```
pd.DataFrame({'Team':['Hawks','Hawks','Hawks','Hawks','Hawks'], 'Season':[1970,1971,1972,1973,1974],'Wins':[40,34,30,46,42]})
```

I would ideally like to compute the sum of the number of wins between 1970 and 1971, 1971 and 1972, 1972 and 1973, etc. An inefficient way would be to use a loop, is there a way to do this using the .groupby function?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a hack, but you could group by `df['Season'] // 2 * 2`, which means dividing by two, taking a floor operation, then multiplying by two again. The effect is to round each year to a multiple of two.

```
df_sum = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Team', df['Season'] // 2 * 2])['Wins'].sum()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Team  Season  Wins
0  Hawks    1970    74
1  Hawks    1972    76
2  Hawks    1974    42
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have years ordered for each team you can just use `rolling` with `groupby` on command. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['Hawks','Hawks','Hawks','Hawks','Hawks'], 'Season':[1970,1971,1972,1973,1974],'Wins':[40,34,30,46,42]})


res = df.groupby('Team')['Wins'].rolling(2).sum()
print(res)
```

```
Out:
     Team    
Hawks  0     NaN
       1    74.0
       2    64.0
       3    76.0
       4    88.0
```